# I have a problem when I try to run python command in bash

Tags: python, bash, command

I'm trying to run this command in bash: `python3 HelloServer.py` (`HelloServer.py` is the python file I want to run). It returns

```
["bash: python3: command not found"][1]
```

and if i run the following command...
`python HelloServer.py` it returns

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HelloServer.py", line 7, in <module>
    from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
ImportError: No module named http.server"
```

this is the bash: [image: output]

this is the HelloServer.py code

Comment: Can you add information which system you are trying to run the command on? Is it debian? If so, what do `which python` and `which python3` print?

Comment: This isn't a Python problem, aside from the fact that you simply don't have Python 3 installed and you are trying to run a Python 3 script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities, first is that as indicated by Bernard you don't have installed python 3, the second is that you do have python 3 installed but you are using python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Based on that module, it looks like the file you're trying to run is meant for python3 which you don't seem to have installed. Easily remedied though: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have python3 installed. Try `which python3` in your shell (Linux). The `http.server` module is for python3 only. If you want to stick to python2, [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) might be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I seems that you haven't python3 on your system.
You need to install python3 first.

**apt-get install pyhton3**
After this you could write command in python3